# Guided Lecture Notes for Calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Last semester I taught Linear Algebra using the standard textbook of Lay. Online one can find nice ["class handouts"](http://www.laylinalgebra.com/free_site/tm_index.html) that serve very well as lecture notes for students to follow along with during class. There are blanks to fill in the bodies of examples and theorems, so students can interact with the notes while not having to try to write down everything said during lecture.

Students responded very positively to these notes, so I'd like to try to craft a similar set of short Calculus lecture notes. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, though, and I'd like to be able to borrow from some *good* guided lecture notes while writing mine.

**Question:** Does anyone know of a particularly good set of Calculus I and II [guided lecture notes](http://www.interventioncentral.org/academic-interventions/study-organization/guided-notes-increasing-student-engagement-during-lecture-) analogous to the Lay notes found above?

Comment: A suggestion: The way your title and question is worded, you are making an assumption that "kinesthetic learner" exists. I view this as a strong claim that may not be necessary to your question, but it really depends on what you intend here. If you are merely looking for recommendations for notes that avoid having students write a lot during lecture *and* perhaps incorporate kinesthetic aspects, then you could remove the assumption about "kinesthetic learners" and just ask for a specific kind of notes (ones that incorporate certain kinesthetic aspects that you could be specific about).

Comment: I note this because a) your request doesn't depend on the assumption, b) your question is not formulated as though you're facing a challenge with "kinesthetic students," and c) you write that "students responded very positively" and not "kinesthetic students responded very positively" (implying benefits students whether or not they have been identified as kinesthetic). Therefore, the assumption seems unnecessary. More importantly, detail about what you're looking for in notes might spark someone's memory and help you get the notes you seek. The disputed construct may just be a distraction.

Comment: I would also add to JPBurke's comments that most people use "kinesthetic" to mean something quite different from filling in blanks on a pre-printed notes template.

Comment: In case you (or anyone else) are (or is) interested: 

The Myth of Learning Styles

http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00091383.2010.503139#.U-o2s_ldV8E

Comment: @all: Indeed I was using the word "kinesthetic" in a very non-technical way, and was shooting for what JPBurke first suggested. Thanks JPBurke!